# Elasticsearch issue with "cluster_uuid" : "_na_" and license in null

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

after install elasticsearch 7.12.1

with this config

```
network.host: 127.0.0.1
http.port: 9200
discovery.seed_hosts: ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
```

in main page of elasticsearch show json

```
{
  "name" : "master",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "_na_",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.12.1",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "zip",
    "build_hash" : "3186837139b9c6b6d23c3200870651f10d3343b7",
    "build_date" : "2021-04-20T20:56:39.040728659Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.8.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

and in xpack license is null

Answer (score 5):

you should add

```
node.name: master
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["master"]
```

to your **elasticsearch.yml** file and restart elasticsearch service

Comment: Can you add docs reference? thanks

Comment: experimental :P